# Google Sheets Formula for Pulling Specific Values in Two Ways

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to do a couple of different things with a spreadsheet in Google and running into some problems with the formulas I am using. I'm hoping someone might be able to direct me to a better solution or be able to correct the current issue I'm having.

First off all, here is a view of the data on Sheet 1 that I am pulling from:

Example Spreadsheet
[image]

The first task I'm trying to accomplish is to create a sheet that lists all of these shift days with the date in one column and the subject ("P: Ben" or S: Nicole") in another column. This sheet would be used to import the data via a CSV into our calendar system each month. I tried doing an Index-Match where it used the date to pull the associated values however I found that I had to keep adjusting the formula offsets in order to capture new information. It doesn't seem like Index-Match works when multiple rows/columns are involved. Is there a better way to pull this information?

The second task I am trying to accomplish is to create a new tab which lists all the dates a specific person is assigned too (that way this tab will update in real time and everyone can just look at their own sheet to see what days they are on-call). However, I run into the same problem here because for each new row I have to change the formula to reflect the correct information otherwise it doesn't pull the correct cell when it finds a match.

I would appreciate any and all information/advice on how to accomplish these tasks with the formula combination I mentioned or suggestions on other formulas to use that I have not been able to find.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Brandon. There are a few ways to attack your tasks, but looking at the structure of your data, I would use curly brackets `{}` to create arrays. Here is an excerpt of how [Google explains](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) arrays in Sheets:

> You can also create your own arrays in a formula in your spreadsheet
>   by using brackets { }. The brackets allow you to group together
>   values, while you use the following punctuation to determine which
>   order the values are displayed in:
>
> - Commas: Separate columns to help you write a row of data in an array.
>     For example, `={1, 2}` would place the number 1 in the first cell and
>     the number 2 in the cell to the right in a new column.
> - Semicolons: Separate rows to help you write a column of data in an array. For
>     example, `={1; 2}` would place the number 1 in the first cell and the
>     number 2 in the cell below in a new row.
>
> **Note**: For countries that use
>   commas as decimal separators (for example €1,00), commas would be
>   replaced by backslashes () when creating arrays.
>
> You can join multiple ranges into one continuous range using this same
>   punctuation. For example, to combine values from A1-A10 with the
>   values from D1-D10, you can use the following formula to create a
>   range in a continuous column: `={A1:A10; D1:D10}`

Knowing that, here's a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TJ2lk8z2frluZZK7FL-Goc9kSbNwmg4tsNoNHNZc4Es/edit?usp=sharing) of your data.

**First Task:**

> create a sheet that lists all of these shift days with the date in one
>   column and the subject ("P: Ben" or S: Nicole") in another column.

To organize dates and subjects into discrete arrays, we'll collect them using curly brackets...

- Dates: `{A3:G3,A7:G7,A11:G11,A15:G15}`
- Subjects: `{A4:G4,A5:G5,A8:G8,A9:G9,A12:G12,A13:G13,A16:G16,A17:G17}`

This actually produces two *rows* rather than *columns*, but we'll deal with that in a minute. You'll note that, because there are two subjects per every one date, we need to effectively double each date captured.

- Dates: `{A3:G3,A3:G3,A7:G7,A7:G7,A11:G11,A11:G11,A15:G15,A15:G15}`
- Subjects: `{A4:G4,A5:G5,A8:G8,A9:G9,A12:G12,A13:G13,A16:G16,A17:G17}`

Still with me? If so, all that's left is to (a) turn these two rows into two columns using the `TRANSPOSE` function, (b) combine our two columns using another pair of curly brackets and a semicolon and  (c) add a `SORT` function to list the dates in chronological order...

`=SORT(TRANSPOSE({{A3:G3,A3:G3,A7:G7,A7:G7,A11:G11,A11:G11,A15:G15,A15:G15};{A4:G4,A5:G5,A8:G8,A9:G9,A12:G12,A13:G13,A16:G16,A17:G17}}),1,TRUE)`

**Second Task:**

> create a new tab which lists all the dates a specific person is
>   assigned too (that way this tab will update in real time and everyone
>   can just look at their own sheet to see what days they are on-call).

Assuming the two-column array we just created lives in `A2:B53` on a new sheet called "Shifts," then we can use the `FILTER` function and `SEARCH` based on each name. The formula at the top of Ben's sheet would look like this:

`=FILTER(Shifts!A2:B53,SEARCH("Ben",Shifts!B2:B53))`

Hopefully this helps, but please let me know if I've misinterpreted anything. Cheers.